# Can zookeeper coordinate across clusters

Tags: locking, apache-zookeeper

**Background:**

We have a single cluster containing 2 app svr nodes n 3 replicated db nodes.  Our application is a .net app, deployed on Linux app svrs.

We will move to a multi-cluster architecture in separate continents in the near future.  Those clusters will replicate our existing cluster.

**Question 1:**

Can I use Zookeeper as means to achieve consistency.  Example: I would like to avoid an operation in NY n a similar operation in EU occurring simultaneously n are inconsistent.

Everything I read about Zookeeper points out to a single cluster solution n I would like to avoid implementing my own distributed locks.

**Question 2:**

Do you have a suggestion different than implementing Zookeeper?

Many thx

Answer (score 0):

The reason I did not get any responses is, more than likely, due to the fact that what I am asking for is impossible at worse, or will bring the clusters to their knees due to the synchronization demands, at best.

I now believe that I will be better off allowing inconsistencies and dealing with them during the eventual consistency sync step.